# Error setting null for parameter with Mybatis and ojdbc14.jar

Tags: java, mybatis, ojdbc

I have an error when setting a parameter as null.

This problem ONLY occurs while using ojdbc14.jar. When using ojdbc6.jar, it is fine.

I have this setting in mybatis configuration xml

```
<settings>
    <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL"/>
</settings>
```

The error message is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting null for parameter #1 with JdbcType NULL . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different jdbcTypeForNull
```

The sql in xml is

```
<update id="rename" parameterType="Element">
    update dsb_element t set t.elementname = #{elementName} where t.elementid = #{elementId}
</update>
```

The java calling it is

```
 com.my.Element ele = new Element();
    ele.setElementId("some-id");
    ele.setElementName(null);
    sqlSession.update(getMyBatisId("rename"), element) ;
```

---

The question is:

Is it a problem of ojdbc14.jar, and if so, why?

I know I can solve it by using #{elementName, jdbcType=VARCHAR2}, but my project has lots of this problem everywhere and it is due soon. I don't want to change all of them.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that since the 3.0.x versions the default JDBC type for null parameters is `Types.OTHER` which not supported by some JDBC drivers like **Oracle 10g**.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=224) a post that explain this issue.

The solution I found is very simple, I set `jdbcTypeForNull` to `NULL` in the configuration file.

```
<configuration>
    <properties resource="mybatis-config.properties" />
    <settings>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL" />
    </settings>

    <environments default="development">
    ....
    </environments>

    <mappers>
    ....
   </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks a lot

Comment: Updated link to the ">Here< a post that explain this issue." in this answer:  https://github.com/mybatis/old-google-code-issues/issues/224